# Open a new tab with custom HTML instead of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm making a Greasemonkey script and would like to open a new tab which will not display a URL but some HTML that is part of the script. So basically I want to do something like this (which is obviously not working):

```
window.open('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');
or
GM_openInTab('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');
```

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: I think it should be possible to do window.open('nonexistingURL'). A new tab will open with a browsers default "page not found". It should be possible to run GM scripts on the non existing url. I'll try that...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can do this:

`var newWindow = window.open();`

and then do

`newWindow.document.write("ohai");`

Comment: Does not work for me, new tab is opened but it’s empty with about:blank in address line :-(.

Comment: I think this translates to a call of `window.open` on the underlying (unsafe) browser window, which would therefore leave your newly-opened window accessible to script on the page you're viewing.  (That's why there's a `GM_openInTab` function after all, to prevent this).

Comment: No, forget what I said above.  It's actually a known bug in GreaseMonkey:  GM scripts treat any attempt to access an empty window as a same-origin security policy violation (which they shouldn't).

Comment: Alternatively, `newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 'ohai';` would work as well.

Comment: Chrome consider it as a pop-up, make sure to allow it (see icon on the right side of the address bar).

Comment: when I use this, opening a window when it start to download a file, the document is reset

Comment: This demo(https://ahuigo.github.io/local-jsfiddle/fiddle.html) shows open page in new tab.

Comment: Works in 2023 (Chrome 115.0.5790.98)

Answer (score 18):

**April 2021 Edit:** This answer is obsolete now. Chrome [banned](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/GbVcuwg_QjM) loading data URIs into the top window, and the [iframe solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url) doesn't work for me in Firefox.

**Original answer:** If the other answer gives you `Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223) about how to handle same-origin policy problems, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481340).

Or, quick and dirty, use a data URI:

```
var html = '<html><head></head><body>ohai</body></html>';
var uri = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(html);
var newWindow = window.open(uri);
```

Comment: Seldom needed, and in most situations there are better ways to troubleshoot "Permission denied to access property document"  errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481340/, etc.

Comment: I edited your correct suggestions into my answer, since the top answer creates this situation for some, and it's too much for a comment.

Comment: Is there a limitation for the length of the data URI?

Comment: I get the following error when I use your answer: "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL"

Comment: Thanks @JCollier, I did some research and marked the answer as obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here just in case anyone will need this. I have made a way to solve this problem, i created a little website (https://tampermonkeykostyl.dacoconutnut.repl.co) that you can give html to in the hash! Example: (you might need to middle click the url for it to actually open in new tab)

```js
// get url
var el = document.getElementById("url");

// make html
var HTML = `
<h1>hi</h1>
if you can see this then cool <br>
<i>this should be italic</i> and <b>this should be bold</b>
`;

// insert html after the link to demonstrate
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", HTML); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432177/14227520

// set url href
el.href = "https://tampermonkeykostyl.dacoconutnut.repl.co/#" + encodeURI(HTML);

// make it open in new tab
el.target = "_blank";
```

```html
<a id="url">Click here to display following HTML in a link (see js):</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's say you have a `.html` file locally stored. What you can do is this:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.location.href = "/path/to/html/file";
```

Comment: No, they can't because (a) They don't have an HTML file locally stored and (b) If they did, that would be a URL relative to the site GreaseMonkey was running on.