# Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, x-frame-options

I am continuously getting the error `"Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'"` while i have already define in my `X-FRAME options` to allow the other domain, like this..

```
 <?php
        header('X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://mydomain.com'); 
    ?>
```

Below is the header of iframe request, clearly shows i have defined to allow the domain to access the iframe but not working. All i want is to resize the iframe using javascript.

[image]

Here is my javascript code to resize the iframe height.

```
<iframe src="http://mydomain.com/xxx/yyy" id="idIframe" onload="iframeLoaded();" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeLoaded() {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
    if(iFrameID) {
          iFrameID.height = "";
          if(iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight < 500) {
              iFrameID.height = "500px";
          } else {
              iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
    }   
}
</script>
```

How can i do this? Please suggest.

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` determines if a page is allowed to be displayed inside a frame. It doesn't grant cross-origin JS permission.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I very recently had this issue myself.
Finally I solved it with the postMessage method.

1. In the document included to the iFrame I check whether it's actually running from an  iFrame.

   ```
   function inIframe(){
       if(top != self){
            var contentHeight = $('#myIframeContent').height(); //Just this part I did with jQuery as I was sure that the document uses it
            postSize(contentHeight);
            }
       }
   ```
2. If the document is running within an iFrame, call a function that we will call postSize.

   ```
   function postSize(height){
        var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : (parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined);

       if(typeof target != "undefined" && document.body.scrollHeight){
           target.postMessage(height, "*");
           }
       }
   ```
3. Add the following code to the document that includes your iFrame

   ```
   function receiveSize(e){
       if(e.origin === "http://www.mywebsite.net"){
           var newHeight = e.data + 35;
           document.getElementById("myIframeID").style.height = newHeight + "px";
           }
       }

   window.addEventListener("message", receiveSize, false);
   ```

Unfortunately I cannot remember the exact sources of all this as I was viewing a lot of different solutions here on Stackoverflow, but also different websites. But this solution works good for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the other solutions use an iFrame ID. It should also work without:

Page within the iFrame which sends a message to outside:

```
<script>
     parent.postMessage('your message', '*');
</script>
```

Parent frame:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  console.log('Message: ',  event.data);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

updating compatability.js to latest version fixed it for me.

Comment: Please mention which version you were using, what you updated it to, and the other software you were using at the time.