# Iframe resize is not working in cross domain in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I am using this script to resize iframe height and width automatically based on the content..

```
<script language="JavaScript">


function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
</script>
```

This script is not working in cross domain servers..Is there any alternate way?

Comment: If you control the content of both domains there is.

Answer (score 0):

I very recently had this issue myself.
Finally I solved it with the postMessage method.

1. In the document included to the iFrame I check whether it's actually running from an  iFrame.

   ```
   function inIframe(){
       if(top != self){
            var contentHeight = $('#myIframeContent').height(); //Just this part I did with jQuery as I was sure that the document uses it
            postSize(contentHeight);
            }
       }
   ```
2. If the document is running within an iFrame, call a function that we will call postSize.

   ```
   function postSize(height){
        var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : (parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined);

       if(typeof target != "undefined" && document.body.scrollHeight){
           target.postMessage(height, "*");
           }
       }
   ```
3. Add the following code to the document that includes your iFrame

   ```
   function receiveSize(e){
       if(e.origin === "http://www.mywebsite.net"){
           var newHeight = e.data + 35;
           document.getElementById("myIframeID").style.height = newHeight + "px";
           }
       }

   window.addEventListener("message", receiveSize, false);
   ```

Unfortunately I cannot remember the exact sources of all this as I was viewing a lot of different solutions here on Stackoverflow, but also different websites. But this solution works good for me.

Someone else previously had this problem and I posted this solution here. It seemed to work fine for him as well:
[Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481340/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document/22481958#22481958)

Cheers