# How to load iframe height dynamically with the content inside iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below is my code which I am using to load iframe content with dynamic height of the iframe content:

```
<iframe id="form-iframe" 
        style="margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;" 
        src="URL" width="300" height="150" scrolling="no" 
        onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()">
</iframe>

function AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad() { 
     document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = \
          document.getElementById("form-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight 
          + "px"; 
}
```

But by using above code in html I am getting below error in console log

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "document"
```

How can I read the height from the content of my iframe to set my `iframe`-container to the same size?

Comment: Is the iframe src on the same domain?  If not you may have problems.  The comments in this accepted answer seem to link to a cross domain solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481340/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document

Comment: Thank you for your response. And yes in src which i use is different domain url. But in javascript if i used " contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight " i am getting that error. Do we have any other method to set height of the iframe dynamically. Can you please help with any example.

Comment: Is there any possibility to load iframe automatically after clicking anything inside iframe where it has to load height automatically depending upon content in iframe.