# iFrameSizer - Not able to set iFrame with dynamic height

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I need to set iFrame with variable height or dynamic as per the content.

Used iFrameSizer library and it is showing following issue. Hereby is the error logged in Console.

```
Error1: Error: Permission denied to access property "document"
custom.js (line 59)
Error2: TypeError: ifRef.contentDocument is null
```

In addition to above context; It is on cross-domains and it is enabled on both domains.

Comment: It would help if you provide more information about how you are using the library. Post your HTML markup and the JS call aswell.

Comment: Solved in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481340/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document