# Open in new window html file stored in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, popup

I have the following javascript variable with HTML code in it:

```
var html_ticket = '<!doctype html>' +
'<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="no-js">' +
'<head> ' +
'   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> ' +

'   ...... ' +

'</body> ' +
'</html> ';
```

I would like to open that variables content as a HTML in a new window.

Is this possible or am i approaching it wrong?

Regards

Comment: Who knows, we haven't seen your approach yet, just a variable containing a string.

Comment: i can't find anything on the net on how to achieve this, that's why i am wondering if this is possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course you can: take a look here:

[Open a new tab with custom HTML instead of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573404/open-a-new-tab-with-custom-html-instead-of-a-url)

```
var newWindow = window.open();
var html_ticket = '<html>...</html>';

newWindow.document.write(html_ticket);
```

#### JS Fiddle demo

Answer (score 2):

You simply use a code like so

```
var newWindow = window.open();
var html_ticket = '<html>...</html>';

newWindow.document.write(html_ticket);
```