# Create HTML element dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I am newer in javascript,so maybe my question will seem nail to some of you.
I have this row it's create div element:

```
 <div id = "popUpWin" style = "width:' + width + 'px; height:' + height + 'px;"></div>;
```

My question is how to create this row dynamically using JavaScript?

Comment: instead of asking SO for solutions for specific problems I would recommend studying the DOM API so you will have solutions for future problems too (teach a man to fish and all that): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add elements to the DOM given plain text HTML using only pure JavaScript (no jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309650/add-elements-to-the-dom-given-plain-text-html-using-only-pure-javascript-no-jqu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways to do this.

1. Use `document.createElement`, which is one of the [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) functions.

   ```
   // Create the element
   var d = document.createElement('div');

   // Set its ID
   d.id = "popUpWin";

   // Set the style properties on the element's `style` object
   d.style.width = width + "px";
   ```

   d.style.height = height + "px";

   ...and then presumably put it somewhere in the document using [`appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-184E7107) or [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-952280727) or similar on another element already in the document.
2. Use `insertAdjacentHTML` on an existing element:

   ```
   theOtherElement.insertAdjacentHTML(
       'beforeend',
       '<div id = "popUpWin" style = "width:' + width + 'px; height:' + height + 'px;"></div>'
   );
   ```

   That example would add the `div` as a child right at the end of the existing element (without disturbing other elements already in it).
3. Use `innerHTML` on an existing element, if you want to **replace** its content:

   ```
   theOtherElement.innerHTML =
       '<div id = "popUpWin" style = "width:' + width + 'px; height:' + height + 'px;"></div>';
   ```

   Note that that will **remove** any other elements inside `theOtherElement` and replace them with just that `div`.