# How to insert HTML content without overwrite the default content with JS

Tags: javascript

I have footer code below. I want to add some html content (see below) but if I do it, the default content disappear. I want to keep default content and add the new one. How to do that?

```
<div id="footer">
HTML content and some classes
</div>
```

And my code to add another HTML content with classes:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = '<div class="bannery"><img class="obrazek" src="URL"></div>';
</script>
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: Look at `appendChild`

Comment: Added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432177/157247) to the dupetarget, as it didn't have the obvious answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : `document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML += '<div class="bannery"><img class="obrazek" src="URL"></div>';`
That should work

Comment: Issue with this is if there is event handlers, you remove them.

Comment: It is supposed to add inject HTML to the element with the footer id

Comment: Usually works for me

Comment: It will add it, just saying there are side effects to this solution.