# Add multiple li to ul at once with Javascript

Tags: javascript

**Scenario**:

I have an HTML unordered list.

I have a button that triggers an AJAX call that returns an HTML string that is a bunch of `<li>...</li>` elements in plain text.

I want to add that bunch of li elements to the ul with Javascript.

**What I know**:

I know I can do something like:

```
newLi = document.createElement("li");
document.getElementById('#the_ul').appendChild(newLi);
```

But I don't know how to do something like:

```
newBunchOfLis = createThemFromHTML('<li>hello</li><li>bye</li>');
document.getElementById('#the_ul').appendChild(newBunchOfLis);
```

**Question**:

What do you suggest?

Comment: [Add elements to the DOM given plain text HTML using only pure JavaScript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309650/add-elements-to-the-dom-given-plain-text-html-using-only-pure-javascript-no-jqu)

Comment: See the linked question's answers. Basically, `document.getElementById("the_ul").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<li>hello</li><li>bye</li>"
);` (note you don't use the `#` with `getElementById`, unless you have the `#` in the `id` attribute, which I don't recommend).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot for your helpful comment. I don't know how much this is a duplicate since the question phrasing also matters. The semantics of "adding a bunch of li's" is not the same as the semantics of "adding HTML". Had I known that second concept before, I would have probably found the answer with a simple Google search.

Comment: Don't think of "duplicate" as "bad." :-) A good duplicate helps others find the answer (in the linked question). But since you went with a string in the question, it seemed reasonable to mark it. (The other way to do it, just FWIW, is a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. That's a great point of view. Really appreciate your effort.