# including raw HTML node to canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jspsych

I want to combine canvas-slider-response [plugin](https://github.com/jspsych/jsPsych/blob/master/docs/plugins/jspsych-canvas-slider-response.md) and RDK [plugin](http:////https://www.jspsych.org/plugins/jspsych-rdk/) to create response trial where observers change the coherence of the motion field using the slider.

The RDK plugin creates a canvas element and append it to the DOM to draw dots on the canvas. Because I want the slider function, inside of the RDK plugin, I added HTML element:

```
var html = '<div id="jspsych-canvas-slider-response-wrapper" style="margin: 100px 0px;">';
html += '<div id="jspsych-canvas-slider-response-stimulus">' + '<canvas id="jspsych-canvas-stimulus" height="' + trial.canvas_size[0] + '" width="' + trial.canvas_size[1] + '"></canvas>' + '</div>';
html += '<div class="jspsych-canvas-slider-response-container" style="position:relative; margin: 0 auto 3em auto; width:';
```

And then add that html variable to the html element with this method:

```
display_element.innerHTML = html;
```

Naturally, this overwrites on the canvas, shows the HTML element, but now the dots are gone (canvas is overwritten?).

I am somewhat aware that rendering HTML into a canvas is severely limited for security reasons. So tried some emulations:

1- I can render html element using creating SVG images:
[Rendering HTML elements to <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652769/rendering-html-elements-to-canvas). But then I can't interact with the images using the methods such as `display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-canvas-slider-response-next').addEventListener('click', function () {}`

2- I can also insertAdjacentHTML but with this method, the canvas element appears after the RDK element shows up at the screen - not together.
[Add elements to the DOM given plain text HTML using only pure JavaScript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309650/add-elements-to-the-dom-given-plain-text-html-using-only-pure-javascript-no-jqu/12042778#12042778).

3- I figured an HTML renderer in JsPsych could solve my problem here. So I tried including the RDK as a stimulus function to the canvas-slider-response, but I can't find a way to call the function within the RDK plugin object. This is what I was trying to achieve:

```
var slider_trial = {
    type: 'canvas-slider-response',
    stimulus: function(c) {
        **callRDKPlugin(c);** ////// Something here /////
    },
    labels: ['Exactly<br>the same','Totally<br>different'],
    canvas_size: [200, 500],
    prompt: '<p>How different would you say the colors of these two squares are?</p>',
    on_finish: function(data) {
        data.color1 = colors[0];
        data.color2 = colors[1];
    }
};
```

Am I missing an easy step?

This is the desired image:

[image: This is the desired image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortening the canvas (height) and appending div node to the HTML,

```
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML= html
    display_element.appendChild(div);
```

solved my problem.